# Is it possible to set custom caller or busy tone for blocked contacts using android?

Tags: android

I have searched a lot but I am not getting any solution to end incoming call and play custom ringtone to caller.

Answer (score 0):

[How to programmatically answer/end a call in Android 4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481524/how-to-programatically-answer-end-a-call-in-android-4-1)

Answer the call with the help of post as above

Then play the audio file with "in call" mode as below

[Trigger an audio file when call is answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395846/trigger-an-audio-file-when-call-is-answered)

And then dont forget to mute the mic :) its just a work around cuz u really can't set an audio from within an app.. All you can do js forward a request to you simcard operator for a custom callertone