# How to play sound when answering phone / How to mod android os

Tags: java, android, rom

I'd like a sound to play every time I answer a call and hang up. I found a similar question with a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395846/trigger-an-audio-file-when-call-is-answered)

I feel confident with C# and have briefly taken a look at Java so the programming shouldn't be a problem but I haven't gotton involved with flashing custom roms or anything before. Where can I start with getting this to work? Do I use the android sdk or will I have to make a custom flash and if so where do I start with that?

Note: I do not want to create an app that does this I'd like it built right in so I can change which sound plays on answer and hang up (if any) in the settings where everything else is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify the default Phone app, source code can be found here https://source.android.com.